Blow up's and contracting Exceptional divisor along a relevant chart (Elementary transformations)
Sorry this is a question due to lack of understanding of blow ups and birationally geometry in general.
Consider the hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}^3$ given by:
$$X =xy - z^2 = 0,$$
which has a singularity at the origin ((0,0,0)). To resolve this singularity, we blow up the origin.
After the blow-up, we cover the space using the following affine charts:

$\textbf{Chart 1:}$ $x \neq 0$ with coordinates $(x, v = \frac{y}{x}, w = \frac{z}{x})$, where the equation becomes:
$$x^2(v - w^2) = 0.$$

$\textbf{Chart 2:}$ $y \neq 0$ with coordinates $(u = \frac{x}{y}, y, w = \frac{z}{y})$, where the equation is:
$$y^2(u - w^2) = 0.$$

$\textbf{Chart 3:}$ $z \neq 0$ with coordinates $(u = \frac{x}{z}, v = \frac{y}{z}, z)$, where the strict transform equation becomes:
$$z^2(uv - 1) = 0$$


The strict transform in Chart 3 intersects the exceptional divisor along the hyperbola (uv = 1).
If I define $X' =uv-1 \subset \mathbb{A}^3$, from chart 3. What is the relation between my original $X$ and $X'$. Is this seen as some type blow and divisorial contraction? Are they birationally to each other? (commutative diagram)
If true how can we describe the canonical divisor relative to these contractions and blow ups. Is there a more general description of this can of birational map?

$X'$ is the strict transform of the corresponding chart in the blowup of the affine space.

So is $X$ Birational to $X'$ and can this be described via a commutative diagram @Sasha

Yes, it is, and yes, it can.

Please keep edits to a minimum.
